# dataset designer relation and crystal report

Tags: c#, datatable, crystal-reports, dataset, dataset-designer

I am using datables in dataset.xsd designer visual studio 2012. I have three tables

tblA,tblB and tblC

```
tblA (parent)   --- ---->  tblB
aid                       bid

tblB(parent)    -- ---->  tblC
nid                     nid
```

if tblB is empty then no data is displaying in  report.I want to show data  in report  if no data is in datable B.

Comment: Left Join instead of Inner Join. You can specifiy that in the relation designer by clicking "select all rows from TblA".

Comment: how can i do left join in dataset desingner visual studio 2012

Comment: there is no button in designers select all rows from tblA.Can you show me through image

Comment: I am making a relation in dataSet designer

Comment: You have to right-click on the relation between both tables, default is INNER JOIN. You can select a different join-type by ticking off "Select all from  TblA", "Select all from TblB" or both (which is a full outer join).

Comment: I will click in links dataset designer .xsd or links in crystal report tab?